# Subsequent anchor tags not working in html/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to alert out individual id of every user on the user link click in html. So, every user is being fetched from the database and displayed on the page as a link. Also, since they have a unique email id, I am trying to alert out their emails when that user link is clicked. My issue is whenever I click on the first one, it alerts out the email, but the second, third or so on, on clicking does not pop up any alert.

**Here is a snippet of the code :**

```
<strong><a href="#" id="post_user" name="post_user" class="<?php echo $messagePost_Email; ?>"><?php echo $messagePost_FirstName.' '.$messagePost_LastName;?></a></strong>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
    $("#post_user").click(function(){
      var element = $(this);
      var emailID = element.attr("class");
      var info = "emailID="+emailID;
      alert(info);
      $.ajax({
        tpye : "POST",
        url : "navigate.php",
        data: info,
        success : function(){

        }
      })
    })
  })

</script>
```

Any suggestions would be of great help since I am not able to  figure out the root cause of this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're probably using the same `id` attribute for every anchor element:

```
<strong><a href="#" id="post_user" ...
```

The `id` attribute is meant to be an **identifier** and as such **must be unique**.

You should get rid of the `id` attribute (if you don't use it elsewhere) and as a jQuery selector use `class` instead. Eg:

```
<strong><a href="#" class="post_user" ...
```

The `emailID` (your user id) store in a [**`data`** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) of the element as it's more clear way of doing such things. This is what the `data` attribute is best to use for.

```
<a href="#" class="post_user" data-emailID="<?php echo $messagePost_Email; ?>" ...
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".post_user").click(function(){
        var emailID = $(this).attr("data-emailID");
        //  or:
        //  emailID = $(this).data("emailID");
        alert(emailID);
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "navigate.php",
            data    : {emailID : emailID},
            success : function(response){
                // ... do anything with "response" ...
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: My other question is if I want to get the value of data-emailID attribute instead of using a jquery here, using $_POST how do I do that, since $_POST only takes name attribute values.

Comment: As for HTML5 - `name` attribute in anchor tag is not valid. You can use it for form elements such as `input`/`select`/`checkbox`/etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong><a href="#" id="post_user1" name='test1@gmail.com'>user1</a></strong>
<strong><a href="#" id="post_user2" name='test2@gmail.com'>user2</a></strong>
<strong><a href="#" id="post_user3" name='test3@gmail.com'>user3</a></strong>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("a").click(function(event){
    // Capture the href from the selected link...
    ids = ['post_user1', 'post_user2'];//add anchor id, at which you want to call this function.
    var id = this.id;
    if($.inArray( id, ids ) != -1) {// check this id is in list.
        var email = this.name;
        var info = "emailID="+email;
        alert(email);
        $.ajax({
            tpye : "POST",
            url : "navigate.php",
            data: info,
            success : function(){

        }
        });
    }
    return false; // not needed if you want the link to execute normally...
});

</script>
```

Comment: [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)